# css footer position stick to bottom of browser?

Tags: css, overflow, position, footer, fixed

I'm having a problem with my site http://artygirl.co.uk/pixie/about/ I can't seem to get the footer to automatically stick to the bottom of the browser, and show the rest of my background. 
Is there a solution better than using position:fixed or absolute?

I think there are possibly other styles over-riding some tests I do in firebug.

Thanks for your help
Regards
Judi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is always a bit difficult, you could increase the `min-height` of your content area, but even then if someone has a really big screen you'd see the same thing.

You could use a bit of JavaScript to increase the `min-height` if someone has a huge viewport but that's still less than elegant. I'm not sure if there is a CSS-only solution to this.

If you want to try the above the code I just posted here: [Is detecting scrollbar presence with jQuery still difficult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571514/is-detecting-scrollbar-presence-with-jquery-still-difficult/2571591) may be of use to you.

Comment: Now I feel determined to come up with a CSS only solution ;-)

Answer (score 41):

**CSS**:

```
.podbar {
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:150;
    _position:absolute;
    _top:expression(eval(document.documentElement.scrollTop+
        (document.documentElement.clientHeight-this.offsetHeight)));
    height:35px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="podbar">
    Put your footer here
</div>
```

This will create a sticky that will always appear at the bottom of the page and overlay everything. Just add extra margin/padding to the bottom of your main container divs equal to the height of footer `+5px` so it doesn't overlay your content.

Works in pretty much every browser I have tested.

Comment: you have position declared twice in here?

Comment: @iwayneo That’s probably on purpose. It looks like the [CSS underscore hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Underscore_hack), with exploits a parsing bug to make Internet Explorer 6 and below read different styles from higher versions and other browsers.

Answer (score 9):

I've used the technique in this article before: [CSS layout: 100% height with header and footer](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/examples/csslayout1.html). It does require some extra markup in your HTML.

Comment: WOW thanks this sounds great. It won't weork on my theme though so I might try it on a different one :)

Comment: That's pretty slick. I'm on my netbook so I can't test it in other browsers though- are there any it doesn't work in?.. IE6?

Comment: I've just implemented this solution on my new portfolio :)

Comment: roryf, that's a nice, simple explanation.  thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

Set the height of html and body to 100%, insert a container div with min-height 100% and relative position, and nest your footer with position: absolute, bottom: 0;

```
/* css */
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}


<!-- html -->
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Identical to what Rory Fitzpatrick posted, minus IE6 compatibility and working demo.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have an example and explanation http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Edit: Since that site is offline, here is another example of this working: https://gist.github.com/XtofK/5317209 and https://codepen.io/griffininsight/pen/OMexrW

```js
document.createElement('header');
document.createElement('footer');
document.createElement('section');
document.createElement('article');
document.createElement('aside');
document.createElement('nav');
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -50px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
footer, .push {
border: 1px solid #ff00ff;
  height: 50px; /* '.push' must be the same height as 'footer' */
}

footer {
  
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" ... />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <p>Your website content here.</p>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ryan Fait's sticky footer is the best!

Answer (score 0):

You could set a `min-height` on `#content`. This won't fix the footer to the bottom of the browser specifically, but will ensure that you can always see a certain amount of the background.

As an alternative, using JavaScript, you could determine the height of the browser window and then calculate the `min-height` for `#content`, and apply it using JavaScript. This would ensure the footer is always in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. Html had a css property for the background saying the colour white.

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer page wise footers because of variable content on pages. I use a top margin of 5em for my footers. Most often than not, we know the height of content that can occur on pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) library for [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), there is also another option. You can use Compass’s [sticky-footer mixin](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/layout/sticky_footer/) ([demo](http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/layout/sticky-footer/)). It requires that the footer be fixed-height, and that your HTML has a certain general structure.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use *position:absolute* use *position:relative* instead.

```
.footer {
   z-index:99;
   position:relative;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
}
```

*position: absolute* will stick it to the bottom of the screen while position relative  won't ignore other divs, so it will stay at the bottom of the full page.