# CSS - make a FLUID height footer stick to bottom of page

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

If the page doesn't have much content, like 300 pixels or so, the footer will appear in the middle of the page on a 1024 resolution.

How could I make my footer show to bottom of the page without knowing the footer height?

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571573/css-footer-position-stick-to-bottom-of-browser) solution:

```
/* css */
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}


<!-- html -->
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but the problem is that I would need to add `padding-bottom: (footerheight);` in the element before the #footer. This is not possible because the footer height is variable depending on the page...

Comment: Not necessarily the most efficient method but you could just have embedded CSS on each page which adjust those specific elements.

Comment: Do you have an option to use Javascript/jQuery?  Seems difficult or impossible to accomplish with just CSS unless you follow Archonix suggestion.

Comment: jquery makes the page "flicker" until the footer gets fixed. if there's a javascript solution that doesn't produce this flicker, yes I'd love to use it :)

Comment: It depends how you accomplish it.  You can have the footer animate up from a `height:0` in order to disguise the fact that it's positioning late, or some-such.  I'll try to take a stab at it after dinner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use min-height on the content area so if u set the min-height to 600px if theres only 300px of content it will pad the footer down another 300px so it isn't in the middle of the screen

Comment: How do you know 600px isn't in the middle of the screen? What if I have 1200px screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can't escape this but there is a trick: make the body background the same as that of the footer and then put all other content inside a container on top of the body.

This will make a 75px footer. Note the related -75px margin of the container div.

```
html {
  height:100%;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
body {
    height:95%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    background-color:#1C303C;
}

footer {
    background-color:#1C303C;
    color:#FFFFA3;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    min-height:75px;
    height:75px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    left:0px;

}

#container {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    margin-bottom:-75px;
}
```

with relevant HTML as follows:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
```