# Detecting presence of a scroll bar in a DIV using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I want to detect the presence of a scroll bar in a DIV using jQuery.  I was thinking to use `$('div').scrollTop()` but that returns 0 in both cases when the scroll bar is at the top and when there is no scroll bar at all.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571514/is-detecting-scrollbar-presence-with-jquery-still-difficult

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059743/detect-elements-overflow-using-jquery

Comment: @moi_meme +1 i was searching for that question to post here :p

Comment: @moi_meme that does not work for DIV's only for the entire window.  I tried adapting it to a DIV but it doesent appear to work.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Assuming `overflow` on the div is `auto`:

```
var div= document.getElementById('something'); // need real DOM Node, not jQuery wrapper
var hasVerticalScrollbar= div.scrollHeight>div.clientHeight;
var hasHorizontalScrollbar= div.scrollWidth>div.clientWidth;
```

Comment: This works too. Thanks.   But unlike in my solution example I posted, In the real world I don't have "IDs" to work with, i am selecting the DIV using jQuery CSS selectors...

Comment: Then use `jQueryElement.get(0)` to get the real DOM node from it http://api.jquery.com/get.

Comment: Whilst this is really useful, is it really the correct answer since it doesn't use any jQuery at all?

Comment: @DanDiplo Remember jQuery is just a JavaScript Library. I'm sure someone could/has written a jQuery plug-in to do the comparison above. But do you really think that level of abstraction is needed?

Comment: @WilliamClemens Personally, no, but that is what the OP asked!

Comment: I don't understand, my page got a v scrollbar, but the var hasVerticalScrollbar is always false. For sure I declared div as to be the DOM tag I want.

Answer (score 19):

```
// plugtrade.com - jQuery detect vertical scrollbar function //
(function($) {
    $.fn.has_scrollbar = function() {
        var divnode = this.get(0);
        if(divnode.scrollHeight > divnode.clientHeight)
            return true;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

example:

```
if($('#mydiv').has_scrollbar()) { /* do something */ }
```

Comment: Great solution compared to the many other examples/attempts to address this issue. I confirmed that this works on IE, FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up finding a solution by doing the following:

Wrap the content that grows with a DIV,  then I detect if a (vertical) scroll bar is present by comparing the height of `wrapperDiv` with the height of `containerDiv` (which normally has the scroll bar if the content is too large).

If the height of `wrapperDiv` is bigger than the height of `containerDiv` then there is a scroll bar, if it is smaller, then there is no scroll bar.

```
<DIV id="containerDiv" style="width:100px;height:100px;overflow:auto;">
    <DIV id="wrapperDiv">
        .... content here...
    </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Comment: Did you try bobince's solution?  His seems like it would work without the extra wrapper div.

Comment: wasn't that the answer from the second link i posted? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059743/detect-elements-overflow-using-jquery

Comment: Yes bobince's solution would work, but unlike in the example i gave above I don't actually have "IDs" to work with.  I'm selecting using jQuery CSS selectors, so I can't use getElementById in order to access clientHeight().  plus I dont trust the raw .clientHeight value as I think it returns slightly different numbers in different browsers, doesen't it?

Answer (score 0):

I will revise what bobince mentioned above since you are asking for jQuery

```
var div= $('#something');
var hasVerticalScrollbar= div[0].scrollHeight > div[0].clientHeight;
var hasHorizontalScrollbar= div[0].scrollWidth > div[0].clientWidth;
```

This is because `scrollHeight` and `scrollWidth` are DOM properties.