# Detect if the DIV have scroll bar or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting presence of a scroll bar in a DIV using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647761/detecting-presence-of-a-scroll-bar-in-a-div-using-jquery)

There is markup as below,

```
<div class="content">Lorem</div>
<div class="content">Lorem Iorem Lorem Iorem Lorem Iorem Lorem Iorem Lorem IoremLorem Iorem Lorem Iorem Lorem Iorem</div>
<div class="content">Lorem</div>
<div class="content">Lorem</div>
```

If content have scroll bar, then it should add class to that div like "scroll-image".

Height can be different for DIVs. Any jQuery solution for this.

Comment: Maybe check if current height is larger than starting height?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
        return this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.height();
    }
})(jQuery);

$('#my_div1').hasScrollBar(); // returns true if there's a `vertical` scrollbar, false otherwise..
```

Taken from [How can I check if a scrollbar is visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814398/jquery-check-if-scrollbar-visible-div-with-overflowauto)

Comment: You have the rep, why no closevote?

Comment: I had a problem for mobile screen having .5 pixels, adding `Math.round` resolved the problem for me:
`return Math.round(this.get(0).scrollHeight) > Math.round(this.outerHeight());`

Answer (score 5):

You need to compare `scrollHeight` with `height` of the element like this:

```
$('.content').each(function(){
  if ($(this)[0].scrollHeight > $(this).height()) {
    $(this).addClass('scroll-image');
  }
});
```

Comment: You have the rep, why no closevote?

Comment: @Esailija: Was writing answer, didn't see :) done

Answer (score 2):

As esailija said, duplicate of: [Detecting presence of a scroll bar in a DIV using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647761/detecting-presence-of-a-scroll-bar-in-a-div-using-jquery)

The solution there was the following

```
var div= document.getElementById('something'); // need real DOM Node, not jQuery wrapper
var hasVerticalScrollbar= div.scrollHeight>div.clientHeight;
var hasHorizontalScrollbar= div.scrollWidth>div.clientWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {
$.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
    return this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.height();
}
})(jQuery);

$('div').hasScrollBar(); //return true if it has one
```

Source: [How can I check if a scrollbar is visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814398/jquery-check-if-scrollbar-visible-div-with-overflowauto)