# How to use "object.addEventListener("resize", myScript)" for a div element?

Tags: javascript, css, resize

before i was trying to add this event listener to a div

i was using "scroll", this one  works but "resize" is not working

and i can't find out why .

This is my code :

```
$('document').ready(function() {

  var content = document.getElementById("scroller");
  var tabs = document.getElementById("tabs");

  var than, now;
  than = tabs.clientHeight;

  content.addEventListener("resize", function(event) {
    now = tabs.clientHeight;

    alert(now + "&" + than);
  }, false);


});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FVfSL/1824/)

or is it possible something like this :

```
$('document').ready(function(){ 

                var content = document.getElementById("scroller");
                var hc , h;

                window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){

                    h = event.clientHeight;
               if(h>510) {
                $(".godown").fadeout("0");
                    }
               if(h<510) {
                content.addEventListener('scroll', function(event){
                 hc =  $('#scroller').scrollTop();






                    if (hc){
                   $(".godown").fadeOut("slow");
                   $(".gotop").fadeIn("slow");
                    }
 if (!hc){
                   $(".godown").fadeIn("slow");
                   $(".gotop").fadeOut("slow");

}
             }, false);
 }
                    }, false);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the event listener to the `window` object, as it is the window resizing, not the element. `window.addEventListener("resize", function(event) {...});`

I have updated [your jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FVfSL/1825/) where you can see it working.

```
$('document').ready(function() {

  var content = document.getElementById("scroller");
  var tabs = document.getElementById("tabs");

  var than, now;
  than = tabs.clientHeight;

  window.addEventListener("resize", function(event) {
     now = tabs.clientHeight;
     alert(now + "&" + than);
     }, false);
});
```

Comment: please check out the Jsfiddle demo

Comment: @LuarbBalla is it not working as you expected? If you resize the window you will get the alert.

Comment: i understand what you are saying as that kind of event can not be listened over another object thanks for making that clear. I still don't get the alert when i click the button that adds the class to make the window bigger.

Comment: @LuarbBalla if you look at the js it is adding a class called bigger which in the css sets the `height` and `width` to `400px`, and changes the background color. when the class is removed again the div returns to original height. The `overflow:auto` gives the scroll in the div. If you remove `overflow:auto` it will  remove the scroll bar.

Comment: The idea is to have live action on the resizing of the window so i can enable or disable dhe buttons to go up or down. In less words to know when a div has a scroll bar or not.

Comment: ah i think you are looking for something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948044/detect-if-the-div-have-scroll-bar-or-not

Comment: Not exactly , i want it to be responsive.