# How to determine with vanilla javascript that a <div> is scrollable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

This question is inaccurately answered here ([Detect if the DIV have scroll bar or not [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948044/detect-if-the-div-have-scroll-bar-or-not/10948074)) and in other questions on SO.

The answers don't take into account that the content of the div may have a `float` that isn't cleared afterwards. The `div.clientHeight` and `div.scrollHeight` can't be used for detecting scrolling behaviour. Like in the following example:

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
  var div = document.querySelector(".container");
  document.querySelector(".clientHeight").innerHTML = div.clientHeight;
  document.querySelector(".scrollHeight").innerHTML = div.scrollHeight;
});
```

```css
.container{
  width: 50px;
  min-height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.floated{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>clientHeight</th>
      <th>scrollHeight</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="clientHeight"></td>
      <td class="scrollHeight"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="container">
  <div class="floated">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blah blah blah blah blah</div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/0t4k4r/pen/PooLygp)

Comment: Are you just referring to vertical scroll? Or scroll in general?

Comment: If you know a solution for vertical scroll, it's enough for me i guess. I could probably take off from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the parent container has `overflow-y`, `overflow-x` or `overflow` that's either `auto` or `scroll`.

javascript for checking if horizontally scrollable:

```
const container = document.getElementByClassName('container');
const overflowY = getComputedStyle(div).overflowY;
const verticallyScrollable = overflowY === "auto" || overflowY === "scroll";
```

Comment: I need to flag the div as scrollable only if its content is actually overflowing it. "overflow: auto" would mark almost all divs as scrollable, since it is the default. Am I correct?

Comment: `Overflow: auto` is not the default, `overflow: none` is

Comment: Basically i am looking if there is a scrollbar, but I didn't want to formulate my question like that, since I think there might be devices that do not display scrollbars.

Comment: So you want to check **dynamically** if the child element is larger than the parent element?

Comment: Oh, you're right. (overflow: visible is actually the default). I guess, it's the right answer then.

Comment: I'd like to know, if there is a element scrolling when wheel event fires.