# How to avoid moving a jsPanel when click its scrollbar in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I use jsPanel and sortable() to make some draggable panels on my site. In IE11, when I click the scrollbar of a panel and just want to scroll its contents, but actually the panel will move with the mouse moving. The right result is in the Chrome: click scrollbar, the panel is fixed and the contents are scroll.
This is my code and 'this._preparePanelTemplate' is a div block.:

```
this.jsPanelOptions = this.options.jsPanelOptions || {
selector: "#" + this.panelContainerId,
template: this._preparePanelTemplate(),
id: this.viewId,
controls: {
maximize: NORMAL_TYPE != this.type,
normalize: NORMAL_TYPE != this.type
},
size: {width: "auto", height: this.H},
title: this.title,
overflow: NORMAL_TYPE != this.type ? "hidden" : "auto",
theme: "default",
draggable: "disabled",
resizable: "disabled"
};
```

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: I have updated my codes. @Raptor

Comment: This problem has been solved referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293197/jquery-ui-sortable-clicking-scrollbar-breaks-it